# CodeIgniter : Run a script from command line if the controller is inside a folder?

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface, codeigniter-2

As stated here :
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

A page like :
http://www.example.com/myController/myFunc/myParam

can be run on the command line as :

```
php index.php myController myFunc myParam
```

My codeignitor set up has some folders to group the controllers, lets say like this :

```
myFolder -> myPageController
         -> myAdminController
```

So, the url becomes :

http://www.example.com/myFolder/myController/myFunc/myParam

How do I call the same thing on CLI ?
Something like :

```
php index.php "myFolder/myController" myFunc myParam
```

Does not seem to work.

Comment: Any idea how to execute http://example.com/beta/app/index.php/notification/test/121 via CLI

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try with :

```
php index.php myFolder myController myFunc myParam1 myParam2 ...
```

Comment: This is not working in my case... :( Maybe another suggestion on how I can fix this?

Comment: This is not working in case also .. Please suggest solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Note, the index method in class file is necessary for work properly in CLI, otherwise codeigniter will return 404 error.

;)

Comment: oh my .. ! Plz help, How can i fix it? return 404 error =.=

Answer (score 1):

For **CodeIgniter 1.7** (if someone is unlucky to have to support a legacy project), there is a solution mentioned [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/6-codeigniter-hacks-for-the-masters--net-8308):

> ### Running CodeIgniter from the Command Line
>
> **The Goal**
>
> Just like the title says, our goal is to be able to run CodeIgniter applications from the command line. This is necessary for building cron jobs, or running more intensive operations so you don't have the resource limitations of a web script, such as maximum execution time.
>
> This is what it looks like on my local Windows machine:
>   [image: Screenshor from the original post]
>
> The above code would be like calling this URL:
>
> http://www.example.com/hello/world/foo
>
> **The Hack**
>
> Create a "cli.php" file at the root of your CodeIgniter folder:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    die('Command Line Only!');
}



set_time_limit(0);

$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $argv[1];

require dirname(__FILE__) . '/index.php';
```

> If you are on a Linux environment and want to make this script self executable, you can add this as the first line in cli.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

> If you want a specific controller to be command line only, you can block web calls at the controller constructor:

```
class Hello extends Controller {

    function __construct() {
        if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
            die('Command Line Only!');
        }
        parent::Controller();
    }

    // ...

}
```